# Passing output of the processing tool to QgsVectorFileWriter using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, merge

Is it possible to pass Processing Tool `native:mergevectorlayers` to a `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3` object

```py
output_folder = r"/home/cirrusklaus/Downloads/tmp/csv/"
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = "csv"
preFix = 'kon_'
lyrList = []

for lyr in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if lyr.name().startswith(preFix) and isinstance(lyr, QgsVectorLayer):
        lyrList.append(lyr.name())
        #path = os.path.join(output_folder, lyr.name()+'.csv')
        #QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(lyr, path, QgsCoordinateTransformContext(), options)
print(lyrList)
#########################################
#Merge wird vorbereitet und ausgeführt
parMerge = {
    'LAYERS': lyrList, #Layer aus der Layerliste werden übergeben
    'CRS': None,
    'OUTPUT': 'memory:'
    }
result1 = processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers", parMerge)
ResMerge = result1['OUTPUT']

path = os.path.join(output_folder,'Tab'+'.csv')
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = "csv"
options.fileEncoding = "utf-8"
transform_context = QgsProject.instance().transformContext()
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(ResMerge, path, transform_context, options)
print("Finished")
```

Comment: Yes it is. Perhaps try `'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'` in the parameters.

Comment: that makes no difference, when I use the processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers", parMerge) occurs the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that when you call the `processing.runAndLoadResults()` method, the `'OUTPUT'` value returned is a layer id string (as opposed to calling `processing.run()` which returns a `QgsVectorLayer` object).

So to get a vector layer object which you can pass to `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3()`, you can do the following:

Add to import statements:

```py
from processing.tools import dataobjects
```

Then:

```py
result1 = processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers", parMerge)
ResMerge = result1['OUTPUT']
context = dataobjects.createContext()
v_lyr = QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString(ResMerge, context)
```

However, while this should answer your current question, I'm not sure why you don't just use an additional processing algorithm (`native:savefeatures`) to which you can pass the layer id string output from the previous processing alg.

```py
output_folder = r"/home/cirrusklaus/Downloads/tmp/csv/"
preFix = 'kon_'
lyrList = []

for lyr in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if lyr.name().startswith(preFix) and isinstance(lyr, QgsVectorLayer):
        lyrList.append(lyr.name())
print(lyrList)
#########################################
#Merge wird vorbereitet und ausgeführt
parMerge = {
    'LAYERS': lyrList, #Layer aus der Layerliste werden übergeben
    'CRS': None,
    'OUTPUT': 'memory:'
    }
result1 = processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers", parMerge)
ResMerge = result1['OUTPUT']
path = os.path.join(output_folder,'Tab.csv')
save_params = {'INPUT': ResMerge,
                'OUTPUT':path}
processing.run('native:savefeatures', save_params)
print("Finished")
```

Comment: thx Ben, I have learned some new PyQIS-Code

Comment: @Klaus, great! You're welcome :-)

Comment: At the beginning of the process I have shp-files at the end it should be a csv-file, therefore I use the object QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3. If i use other processing tools, is the processing tool "processing.run('native:savefeatures', save_params)" to be used at the end or at each step of the process?

Comment: @Klaus, not too sure what you mean. Just use it to write any temporary output layers which you want to save to a file location. You can use it after any other processing step or at the end of a chain of algorithms to save the output to a file location. It's simply a quick alternative to using the `QgsVectorFileWriter` class. Being a processing alg, it's quite versatile. The 'INPUT' param can be a path ('path/to/some.shp'), a `QgsVectorLayer` object or a layer id string.

Comment: Of course, you can pass a file location as the output of any processing alg, I suggested save features here since you want to load the merged layer and save it as a csv.